# How do I ensure that NInject2 disposes of objects in the correct order?

Tags: ninject, ninject-2

Specifically, if I use NInject to create a bunch of objects that have been bound in singleton scope, I expect NInject to release them in reverse order.

I have a test case as follows, I want to know if I am doing something wrong, or if NInject2 has a bug.

I expect to see that, given that I have created an instance of Foo, and then an instance of Bar, NInject should be releasing Bar before it releases Foo! Why isn't it doing this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Ninject;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    interface IFoo
    {
    }

    interface IBar
    {
    }

    class Foo : IFoo, IDisposable
    {
        public Foo()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Created Foo Instance");
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Disposed Foo Instance");
        }
    }

    class Bar : IBar, IDisposable
    {
        public Bar(IFoo foo)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Created Bar Instance");
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Disposed Bar Instance");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel())
            {
                kernel.Bind<IBar>().To<Bar>().InSingletonScope();
                kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InSingletonScope();

                kernel.Get<IFoo>();
                kernel.Get<IBar>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actual output:

```
Created Foo Instance
Created Bar Instance
Disposed Foo Instance
Disposed Bar Instance
```

Expected output:

```
Created Foo Instance
Created Bar Instance
Disposed Bar Instance
Disposed Foo Instance
```

Comment: (Incidentally, I'm using the "no web" version for .NET 4.0, so that I can use NInject on .NET 4.0 Client Profile)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ninject doesn't have reference counting at the moment. Therefore the instances are disposed in any order. If you want this you would have to write a ICache implementation which has reference counting.

Alternatively you can use define that Foo is in the scope of Bar using named scope. This will ensure that Foo won't be disposed before Bar.

Comment: You don't need reference counting to do this - all you have to do is append each created item to a list...  And then dispose of them in reverse order.  Reference counting would add more problems than it would solve.  That said, looking at https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Activation/Caching/ICache.cs it seems that this could be very simple to for me to implement, how should I go about substituting the NInject implementation for my own?

Comment: For now, I've stopped using .InSingletonScope(), and now explicitly rebind the few true singletons that I use to constants, because I can't define Foo in Bar's scope. If I used scopes like that, I would miss out of NInject's ability to declaratively define the dependencies. (I use conventions-based binding)

Comment: That all actually answers the question perfectly, and it looks like I should be able to (rather elegantly) implement this back at work, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately there is much more involved if you want to dispose in reverse order, so that just using a list won't do it. E.g. not all objects are in singleton scope. There are other shorter lived scopes too.

Comment: Hmm, that would complicate it.  Now that I think of it, I think you're trying to solve a more complicated situation where NInject is used as a service locator throughout the project, rather than only as a means of autowiring in Program.cs.  I think for me, using a reversed list will work because of that - I have only one scope, and it introduces the right semantics.  Ordinarily I would be happy with transcient scope, except that 'Foo' and 'Bar' in this situation are C++ objects, and I need them disposed predictably.  Are there any documents that discuss ownership semantics in NInject projects?